# High Sierra very slow Finder update

Tags: finder, high-sierra

I have recently formatted my MacBook Pro and installed High Sierra (v10.13.6). Ever since, although I do not have many apps installed, finder changes are shown very lately..

For example: I take screenshots With keyboard shortcuts, they appear on desktop after some MINUTES..
Or: I delete 100-150 files, they are still shown on finder window for some time, some of them without thumbnails..

Does somebody have the same problem?

Finder relaunch fixes everything. But I have to relaunch Finder after every change..

Here is a screenshot of finder after I deleted some files. See the last column where "the kind of file" is shown. The removed files are still shown, but without any kind:

[image]

Comment: I had an external drive that I formatted APFS and partitioned two ways. Partition A I was able to use smart folders in to search the entire partition, however partition B couldn't. I had to reformat the entire drive by wiping it and doing a GUID scheme APFS format. Did you do this?

Comment: I have just one disk without partitioned. Bit I think this is a bug by the new APFS file format.. With the old "Mac OS Extended" I did not have any problem

Comment: That is why I mentioned my situation. Did you completely wipe you disk from recovery and install high sierra via a USB or something?

Comment: @Jahhein yes...

Comment: Double check you didn’t change any file permissions? Especially for your home folder. That ended up being a key hint for my issue.

Comment: everything looks ok there..

Comment: Do it in another user? Guest would probably be best as it won’t have any login items or special permissions. If you can replicate it, hope it isn’t hard drive failure

Comment: This Q is old, but I'm having this issue as well on three different machines from different era's. This is most likely an OS X issue, not individual set up. The file system is a likely culprit I suppose. Did any solution pop up?

Comment: Nope. I still have the same problems..

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a problem with Finder's external sync (described in [the thread on MacRumors](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/desktop-slow-to-refresh.2094210/)).

This slowness was linked to 3rd party file sync applications (Google Drive, Syncovery, SugarSync, etc). There is no simple solution so far.

There is also a related [Apple Communities' thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8371265).

Answer (score 0):

I started experiencing this problem a few days ago after installing a utility called Funter which sits in the top menubar. Quitting it makes everything snappy again. So check what third-party stuff you've installed that runs all the time.